# How to position a table at the center of div horizontally & vertically

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment, centering

We can set a image as background image of a `<div>` like:

```
<style>
    #test { 

        background-image: url(./images/grad.gif); 
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center; 

        width:80%; 
        margin-left:10%; 
        height:200px; 
        background-color:blue;

    }

</style>

<div id="test"></div>
```

I need to set a table at the center of a `<div>` horizontally & vertically. Is there a cross-browser solution using `CSS`?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Centering is one of the biggest issues in CSS. However, some tricks exist:

To center your table horizontally, you can set left and right margin to auto:

```
<style>
  #test {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }
  table {
    margin: 0 auto; /* or margin: 0 auto 0 auto */
  }
</style>
```

To center it vertically, the only way is to use javascript:

```
var tableMarginTop = Math.round( (testHeight - tableHeight) / 2 );
$('table').css('margin-top', tableMarginTop) # with jQuery
$$('table')[0].setStyle('margin-top', tableMarginTop) # with Mootools
```

No `vertical-align:middle` is possible as a table is a block and not an inline element.

#### Edit

Here is a website that sums up CSS centering solutions: http://howtocenterincss.com/

Comment: Silly table. Thanks, this (margin:0 auto) helped me as well.

Comment: What is `testHeight` here?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni the height of the `#test` element. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out.... Please elaborate `javascript`, `jQuery`, `AJAX` etc so that others can understand

Comment: Just what I need! I have been fiddling with paddings, margins for a few hours!

Comment: Thanks,`margin: 0 auto;` helped me `<div style="width: 600px;margin: 0 auto;"><table></table></div>`

Comment: I would consider this the best answer a few years ago, but since the introduction to flex, it is usually preferable to do so, look at jdlin's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35383281/10529638 using display: flex and justify-content: center on the parent div.

Comment: `margin: auto;` would center both vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 48):

Here's what worked for me:

```
#div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#table {
  align-self: center;
}
```

And this aligned it vertically and horizontally.

Comment: This must be the best answer!

Answer (score 15):

To position horizontally center you can say `width: 50%; margin: auto;`. As far as I know, that's cross browser. For vertical alignment you can try `vertical-align:middle;`, but it may only work in relation to text. It's worth a try though.

Answer (score 13):

Just add `margin: 0 auto;` to your `table`. No need of adding any property to `div`

```html
<div style="background-color:lightgrey">
 <table width="80%" style="margin: 0 auto; border:1px solid;text-align:center">
    <tr>
      <th>Name </th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>US </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>India </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
<div>
```

Note: Added background color to div to visualize the alignment of table to its center

Answer (score 7):

Additionally, if you want to center both horizontally and vertically -**instead of having a flow-design (in such cases, the previous solutions apply)**- you could do:

1. Declare the main div as `absolute` or `relative` positioning (I call it `content`).
2. Declare an inner div, which will actually hold the table (I call it `wrapper`).
3. Declare the table itself, inside `wrapper` div.
4. Apply CSS transform to change the "registration point" of the wrapper object to it's center.
5. Move the wrapper object to the center of the parent object.

```css
#content {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: red;
  position: relative;
  }

#wrapper {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; top: 50%; /*move the object to the center of the parent object*/
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /*these 5 settings change the base (or registration) point of the wrapper object to it's own center - so we align child center with parent center*/
  }

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: You cannot get rid of the wrapper div, since this style does not work directly on tables, so I use a div to wrap it and position it, while the table is flowed inside the div.

Answer (score 5):

You can center a box both vertically and horizontally, using the following technique :

### The outher container :

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container :

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`
- should have `text-align: center;`

### The content box :

- should have `display: inline-block;`

If you use this technique, just add your table (along with any other content you want to go with it) to the content box.

### **Demo :**

```css
body {
    margin : 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position : absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding : 20px;
    border : 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        <em>Data :</em>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tom</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Anne</td>
                <td>15</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gina</td>
                <td>34</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/621/)!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I had to include

```
body { width:100%; }
```

for "margin: 0 auto" to work for tables.

Answer (score 1):

As I can't comment yet, I will post my comment to [jdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5923088/jdlin) here. If you want to accomplish this without styling the table itself, you could do:

```css
#div 
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29800867)

Answer (score 0):

Using simple javascript at the bottom after loading finishes ...

```
  <script>
    var div = document.getElementById("test");
    var table = document.getElementById("tabel");
    var tableMarginTop = Math.round( (div.offsetHeight - table.offsetHeight) / 2 );
    document.getElementById("tabel").style["margin-top"] = tableMarginTop;
  </script>
```