# How do I Align a table

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2010

I have a table on my webpage, and it automatically aligns to the left, the text is aligned in the center which is what I want, but I am unable to get the table to align to the center of the page.

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;  width:300px">
    <tr>

            <td colspan="2">
                <b>&nbsp;Change Your Passwordsword</b>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>
                New Password: 
            </td>    
             <td>
                <input type="password" id="pwd1" name="pwd1" size = "8" />&nbsp;
              </td>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Confirm Password: 
            </td>
                    <td>

                <input type="password" id="pwd2" size = "8" name="pwd2" />&nbsp;
              </td> 
            </tr>  
            <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>

                <input type="submit" value="Confirm" /></td>

            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:Literal ID="msg" runat="server" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Here is the code for my table.

Comment: Align in the `<body>`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059394/how-to-position-a-table-at-the-center-of-div-horizentally-vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe the following css property

```css
table{
margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<table style="border: 1px solid black;  width:300px">
    <tr>

            <td colspan="2">
                <b>&nbsp;Change Your Passwordsword</b>
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>
                New Password: 
            </td>    
             <td>
                <input type="password" id="pwd1" name="pwd1" size = "8" />&nbsp;
              </td>
            <tr>
            <td>
            Confirm Password: 
            </td>
                    <td>

                <input type="password" id="pwd2" size = "8" name="pwd2" />&nbsp;
              </td> 
            </tr>  
            <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>

                <input type="submit" value="Confirm" /></td>

            </tr> 
            <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:Literal ID="msg" runat="server" />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g92w2cL1/)

Add `align="center"` to the `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

It will center your table.

Check: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu4883s1/).

Answer (score 0):

To center a table, you need to set the margins, like this:

`table.center {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
  }`

And then do this:

`<table class="center">`
    ...
  `</table>`

At this point, Mozilla and Opera will center your table. Internet Explorer 5.5 and up, however, needs you to add this to your CSS as well:

`body {text-align:center;}`