# Having trouble centering a DIV element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, centering

Here is my JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xdmns7e4/

HTML:

```
    <!-- Stream starting soon alert popup -->
    <div class="streamStartingSoon" id="infor">
            <font color="white"><strong>Stream will begin shortly!</strong></font>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.streamStartingSoon{
    width: 250px; 
    height: 30px; 
    background-color: #65d1d4;
    opacity:0.9;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    line-height: 30px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 250px;
```

JS:

```
jQuery("#infor").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
```

I can't seem to get this code centered on my website... Any ideas?

Comment: I need it to float above the other content on my website before it disappears FYI

Answer (score 0):

You can horizontal center an absolute positioned element with adding `50%` to the left minus the half of the width of your element (and same for the height):

```
.streamStartingSoon {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -125px; /* Half the width */
}
```

Whole code:

```js
jQuery("#infor").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
```

```css
.streamStartingSoon {
  width: 250px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #65d1d4;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px; /* Half the height */
  margin-left: -125px; /* Half the width */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Stream starting soon alert popup -->
<div class="streamStartingSoon" id="infor">
  <font color="white"><strong>Stream will begin shortly!</strong></font>
</div>
```

See this [article on CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/).

`transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` is also possible, but negative margins are more compatible with old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "position: absolute;" from your CSS and add Center tags

HTML

```
<!-- Stream starting soon alert popup -->
<div class="streamStartingSoon" id="infor">
    <center><font color="white"><strong>Stream will begin shortly!</strong</font></center>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.streamStartingSoon{
width: 250px; 
height: 30px; 
background-color: #65d1d4;
opacity:0.9;
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle; 
line-height: 30px; 
/*position: absolute;*/
top: 250px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are positioning it absolutely.
To move it around use `top`,`bottom`,`left`,`right`. set them all to 0.

Try this:

```js
jQuery("#infor").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
```

```css
.streamStartingSoon{
  width: 250px; 
  height: 30px; 
  background-color: #65d1d4;
  opacity:0.9;
  text-align: center; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  line-height: 30px; 
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="streamStartingSoon" id="infor">
  <font color="white"><strong>Stream will begin shortly!</strong></font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059394/how-to-position-a-table-at-the-center-of-div-horizontally-vertically) for more information about div{display:table}, centering  and ect.

```js
jQuery("#infor").delay(4000).fadeOut("slow");
```

```css
html,body{ /*it for .div-table, to calculate page height and width, but you can also change for any element which inherit (before) of .div-table*/
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.div-table{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:table;
}
.div-center{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.streamStartingSoon{
  width: 250px; 
  height: 30px; 
  background-color: #65d1d4;
  opacity:0.9;
  text-align: center; 
  line-height: 30px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Stream starting soon alert popup -->
<div class="div-table">
  <div class="div-center">
     <div class="streamStartingSoon" id="infor">
        <font color="white"><strong>Stream will begin shortly!</strong></font>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```